# PHP call function/method between class file

Tags: php, class

I need to call a function from a separate class file, let says:

```
class Functions {

    public function seoUrl($string)
    {
       $string = strtolower($string);
       $string = preg_replace("~[^\p{L}\p{N}\n]+~u", "-", $string);
       $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);
       $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $string);
       return $string;
    }

}
```

I want `Functions::seoUrl()` to be call in another class file:

```
class Product {

    public function goto_url($url)
    {
       return Functions::seoUrl($url);
    }

}
```

I get error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Functions' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs...

Comment: Not really too great at php but a few questions to help possible answerers. Is the class in another file? And the function you're trying to call doesn't seem to be a static function, meaning it shouldn't work unless you instantiate it.

Comment: Did you use `require` to load your class `Functions`?

Comment: @A.Lau Thank you, I had `public static function seoUrl($string)` and now I can use all method across separate classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions::seoUrl() is the way to call static method. You need to declare your method seoUrl(string) as static, or create an object for your Functions class

```
$functions = new Functions();
$functions->seoUrl(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you getting fatal just because your `PHP` is not able to locate `class Functions` For this you have two options either you `require` that file or add some `autoloading` for this.

```
<?php

require_once 'Functions.php'// where your Class functions resides.

class Product
{

    public function goto_url($url)
    {
        return Functions::seoUrl($url);
    }

}
```